# Make CSS3 transitions go with constant tempo

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

Is it possible to make transitions in css3 go with constant tempo? I mean, they slow down in the end, in most cases it looks cool but not if you want to make e.g. timer(with div go smaller and smaller).

Answer (score 4):

Use the `linear` keyword for the transition timing function. Something like this:

```
transition: all 1s linear;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
transition-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
```

The default (inherent) value is `ease`, so add this line and change it to linear. This does not work in IE9 or older.